# IndentationError: unexpected indent 321

Tags: python, indentation

Can anyone help me with this unexpected indent error?

```
    try:
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
        checkboxes = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//tr[*]//td[1]//lable[@class='_55sg _kv1']//input[@name='select_single_row_checkbox[]']")))


        while len(checkboxes):
            checkboxes -= 1

         for checkbox in checkboxes:
            if not checkbox.isSelected():
              checkbox.click()
         if len(checkboxes) < 0:
                break

        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)")

    except NoSuchElementException:
                 print("NoSuchElementException")
```

I'm getting multiple errors on indentation when adding this code to PyCharm

Comment: Your indentation is inconsistent. Sometimes you use 4 spaces, sometimes 3, sometimes 2. Pick one and stick with it.

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it, your message in your error section is tabbed a bit too much